# PHPMailer won't send with SSL but Outlook will

Tags: php, email, ssl, phpmailer

I'm having a problem trying to send an email on my local machine using PHPMailer and SSL (works fine without SSL), and I don't know where to start finding where the error is coming from.

Error:

> 2015-02-08 01:13:29   Connection: opening to
>   ssl://mail.mydomain.com:465, t=300, opt=array ( ) 2015-02-08
>   01:13:29  SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) 2015-02-08
>   01:13:29  SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be sent.Mailer
>   Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Here's my code I'm using to send:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.mydomain.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'admin@mydomain.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxxx';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'admin@mydomain.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('personalemail@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient
```

This is what I have tried/observed:

- The same code works fine from my server (where the email server is also stored)
- Without SSL, I can send an email from either my local host or server.
- I can send a mail using a gmail account WITH SSL from my home computer and PHPMailer.
- Using the same settings as the above code, I can send/receive messages over SSL at home using Microsoft Outlook (asks if I want to accept Certificate).
- I have tried flushing the DNS (using `ipconfig /flushdns`), but it did nothing.

I really don't know where to start looking, because I can send messages over ssl using a gmail account, but not with my own account, however I can if I use outlook.

Any ideas where I'm screwing up?

Edit:

nslookup results:

```
C:\Users\xxx>nslookup mail.xxxx.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    xxxx.com
Address:  110.232.yyy.zzz (this is correct)
Aliases:  mail.xxxx.com
```

---

```
$ openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect mail.xxxx.com:465
CONNECTED(00000003)
```

---

```
$ openssl s_client -crlf -connect mail.xxxx.com:465
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, ST = Illinois, L = Chicago, O = "Trustwave Holdings, Inc.", CN = "Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2", emailAddress = ca@trustwave.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.zuver.net.au/O=Zuver Pty Ltd/L=Narre Warren/ST=VIC/C=AU
   i:/C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=Trustwave Holdings, Inc./CN=Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2/emailAddress=ca@trustwave.com
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=Trustwave Holdings, Inc./CN=Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2/emailAddress=ca@trustwave.com
   i:/C=US/O=SecureTrust Corporation/CN=SecureTrust CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFLTCCBBWgAwIB...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=*.zuver.net.au/O=Zuver Pty Ltd/L=Narre Warren/ST=VIC/C=AU
issuer=/C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=Trustwave Holdings, Inc./CN=Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2/emailAddress=ca@trustwave.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3822 bytes and written 624 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 150CD8E826D73DD132572E...
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: CCB6C3F...
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 57 3a ...

    Start Time: 1423438080
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
220-zzz.zuver.net.au ESMTP Exim 4.84 #2 Mon, 09 Feb 2015 10:27:59 +1100
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited,
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
```

Comment: are you using apache?

Comment: @noob Yes, I forgot to mention php_openssl.dll is enabled also.

Comment: did you try with port 587?

Comment: @noob Yes just then, no luck.

Comment: did you try turning off your firewall

Comment: @noob Yes, both in Windows and router. Didn't work

Comment: Did you try testing if you can connect to mail.mydomain.com on port 465 from the host that your php script is running on, using some other program, such as openssl?

Comment: @mti2935 I'm not familiar with openssl, but with a quick google I tried it and got CONNECTED(00000003), but nothing after that (I got the same result on my hosting server via ssh, so it's probably my lack of understanding of openSSL). However, as I said, mail.mydomain.com 465 works on Outlook (using SSL).

Comment: Have you tried tls on port 587? Have you tried the things mentioned in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)? Are you running PHP 5.6? Are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @Synchro Yes, yes, yes, not sure. I've done a lot of testing and it seems it has something to do with PHP 5.6 - I've posted another question trying to find out. How do I know if it's a self-signed certificate or not?

Comment: Is PHP running on the same machine as outlook? The thing is this is failing early on, suggesting a fairly basic networking problem - DNS, firewall etc. PHP 5.6 verifies ssl certs - earlier versions do not, and it would fail with a self-signed cert on the server. You can see who signed the cert using openssl connect.

Comment: Yes, same machine as outlook. I had a look through wireshark, and it does make a connection with the server - the final packet I received said it lost connection or something along those lines. Cert is from Trustwave, however I have not purchased a cert myself, so this is from the hosting provider.

Comment: Try changing `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` to `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`  Does that make a difference?

Comment: Just to rule out a DNS problem - at the command line, type `nslookup mail.mydomain.com`.  Does it resolve to the correct IP for mail.mydomain.com?  Also, to rule out a problem with PHP or PHPMailer, please post the output of these two commands:  `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect mail.mydomain.com:465` and  `openssl s_client -crlf -connect mail.mydomain.com:465 `

Comment: OK, so this shows that openssl on the same host is able to connect to mail.mydomain.com on port 465 using SSL.  But for some reason, PHPMailer is not able to do the same.  Try adding `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` to your script.  This should output some debugging info as to what is going on when it tries to connect, which may shed some light on the problem.

Comment: @mti2935 Yes, I've tried various debugging levels however they all give the same generic message. I think it's to do with PHP 5.6, because the same code works with PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further testing, the problem happens only with PHP 5.6. It worked fine with PHP 5.5.

The reason is due to changes to OpenSSL in PHP 5.6, as outlined in [this](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php) appendix, specifically:

> Stream wrappers now verify peer certificates and host names by default
>   when using SSL/TLS

As I was with a shared hosting plan, the SSL certificate was for `server1.myhosting.com`, and I was accessing my mail server by `mail.mydomain.com`. There is a mismatch because the SSL Certificate is issued for `server1.myhosting.com`

Changing my code to

```
$mail->Host = 'server1.myhosting.com';
```

fixed it for me.

N.B. I was advised to use `server1.myhosting.com` by my web hosting provider, so this might not work for you.

Comment: There's a problem description and workatound for v5.2.10+ at the PHPMailer wiki: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#php-56-certificate-verification-failure